# using class attributes function in class method - python

Tags: python, python-2.x, class-attributes

I'm trying to use this code in python:

```
class A:
    func = lambda: "go away"
    @classmethod
    def apply(cls):
        cls.func()
A.apply()
```

And I receive this error:

```
unbound method <lambda>() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: it's a class method - it needs to be `func = lambda cls: ...` ...

Comment: You cannot declare lambdas as class/static functions in Python 2.x. Your code should work in Python 3.x, to the horror of everyone looking at it. Why would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: In my original code, the "go away" is service function, defined somewhere else. The apply function, is a factory method, that uses this function. func is defined from outside.

Comment: using `func = lambda cls: ...` hasn't helped. it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `apply(A)` works. However you will need to fix the issues with `func` as well.

Answer (score 0):

So here you have a bunch of problems. I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve, but you definitely have to take another look on documentation.
First, take a look on your class. 
Inside you want to specify a function, and Python uses a `def func(args)` method to it. If you want to use it inside a class, you should use `self` as a parameter.

**From the documentation:**

```
class MyClass:
    """A simple example class"""
    i = 12345

    def f(self):
        return 'hello world'
```

Also, `lambda`, in words is an anonymous function. When you define it, you should do something like:

```
s = lambda x: x**2
s(2)
```

and `x` would be your function parameter, and `x**2` something you want to return, so the function will return 4.

Hope it will reduce some mess and you will write your code in a better way. Good luck!

Comment: I've simplified my code so it won't be much to read, but i've reasons to do it this way, as i've mention in a comment above. Do you know any way to preserve this functionality, in a different way?

Comment: Take a look on your error. Lambda function needs 2 arguments, as I explained in my answer. And there's nothing to do with your oversimplified code with syntax errors, sorry, that's not enough.

Comment: i'm sure you're mistaken, about the 2 arguments. I guess you are right about the definition of lambda inside a class, that a `self` first argument is required.

Comment: I've also tried to define the function in another module, and it still wont let me to run it in the classmethod method.